# Gulp fails to update css file during gulp.watch

Tags: gulp

I'm having a strange issue that I can't figure out regarding gulp.

I have a gulp-sass task. When I change any of my .scss files I want it to recompile my sass files. Pretty simple.

This is my code

#### gulp-task

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
  gulp.src('app/styles/app.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: require('node-bourbon').includePaths
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets'));
});
```

#### gulp-watch

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
   gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', ['sass']);

});
```

The problem is. When I run gulp watch it all acts normally. If I edit a .scss file it runs the task again. However the changes aren't reflected in the rendered .css file.

The curveball is if I press ctrl+c to stop the gulp.watch cycle THEN the changes are reflected in the rendered .css file

I'm wondering what is causing this to happen.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see the behavior you describe when using your tasks, which makes me think the problem is either environmental or elsewhere in your gulpfile. Could you post the smallest complete `gulpfile.js` that exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem using PHPStorm. It being my first gulpfile I was just experimenting with dummy html, js, and css, and looking at the generated code within the IDE. My code never updated after watch events!

Finally, I actually loaded site in browser...

When you look in browser the files **are** being updated, but for some reason they are not indexed by the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and what fixed it for me is that I was in the wrong directory in Terminal. As soon as i cd'd to the directory containing the gulp file, all was well and changes were detected.

Comment: Such a simple thing can be so hard to trace.

Answer (score 1):

Callback must be a function, not an array of task names. Try:

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
  watch('js/*/.js', function() {
    gulp.start('scripts');
  });
});
```

You need to check your source directory or you need to update your dependencies. See related discussion

Check this thread as well: https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/issues/214#issuecomment-171282193